# Как переопределить отступ у menuItem в navigation drawer?

Tags: android

Необходимо выровнять элементы меню относительно элементов в header. Как это сделать?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Насколько я помню вот так можно изменить horizontal padding у элементов меню

```
<com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        ...
        app:itemHorizontalPadding="16dp"
        .../>
```

Соответственно, указывайте значение которое необходимо. Думаю тут относительно header'a только на глаз)